# cast string column to decimal in scala dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, casting

I have a dataframe (scala)
I am using both pyspark and scala in a notebook

```
#pyspark
spark.read.csv(output_path + '/dealer', header = True).createOrReplaceTempView('dealer_dl')

%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.sql("select * from dealer_dl")
```

How to convert a string column (amount) into decimal in scala dataframe.

I tried as below.

```
 %scala
 df = df.withColumn("amount", $"amount".cast(DecimalType(9,2)))
```

But I am getting an error as below:

> error: reassignment to val

I am used to pyspark and quite new to scala. I need to do by scala to proceed further. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in scala you can't reasign references defined as `val` but `val` is immutable reference. if you want to use reasigning some ref you can use `var` but better solution is not reasign something to the same reference name and use another `val`.
For example:

```
val dfWithDecimalAmount = df.withColumn("amount", $"amount".cast(DecimalType(9,2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable solution. I tried the solution but I get "error: not found: value DecimalType" as error now. I also added "import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes._" in that cell. Thanks.

Comment: @Lilly try to import `import org.apache.spark.sql.types._`